# Transfering data from one form to another using Java

Tags: java, mysql, forms

There are two forms which are linked to only one table in the database. One form inserts the data into the table, the other retrieves it. I wrote the coding through one form, but it doesn't work. Here's the code snippet for the first form (fashion_and_footwear):

```
    int dress1=100;
double price1=Double.parseDouble(Price1.getText());
DefaultTableModel CurrentPurchases= new DefaultTableModel();
int rows=CurrentPurchases.getRowCount();
if (rows>0){
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    CurrentPurchases.removeRow(0); }
}
try{
    Connection connection=getConnection();
    stmt=connection.createStatement();
    String Buy1Query1="Update Products set Quantity=Quantity-1 where Product_no=1;";
    String Buy1Query2="Insert into Buy values('"+Pname1.getText()+"',"+price1+");";
    stmt.executeUpdate(Buy1Query1);
    stmt.executeUpdate(Buy1Query2);
    dress1--;
    if(dress1==0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sorry, This Item is Out of Stock!");
    }
    new ShoppingCart().setVisible(true);
    String Pname="";
    double Price;
    PreparedStatement buyquery=connection.prepareStatement("Select * from Buy;");
    rs=buyquery.executeQuery();
    if(rs.next()){
    Pname=rs.getString("ProductName");
    Price=rs.getDouble("Price");
    CurrentPurchases.addRow(new Object[]{Pname,Price});
    }
}
catch(SQLException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
    ex.getErrorCode();
}
finally{}
```

This is the table I created:

```
create table Buy(ProductName varchar(100),Price decimal(7,2));
```

The data is inserted into the back-end table, but it is not transferred to the other form (ShoppingCart). What should I do? 
NOTE: There is already a table component named CurrentPurchases in the ShoppingCart form.

Comment: After assigning `Pname` and `Price`, what is their value? (You can obtain it with `System.out.println(Pname);`

Comment: Pname is String value and Price is Decimal value.

Comment: Ok, but, do they have the expected String and Decimal values? I mean, does your code `SELECT` the right values from database?

Comment: No, it's showing some other value but from the same table.

Comment: So, you have several rows in `Buy`? And which is the one that you one to get from database?

Comment: It showed display the latest value added. would this code be correct: `select * from buy where productname='"+price1.getText()+"';`

Comment: I think I've got it. I'm going to post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in comments, the problem is that data selected after insert is not the last inserted row. So, there're 2 possible solutions.

The first and best one would be to add an autoincrement column to `Buy` as it's primary key. You can use an SQL statement similar to:

```
ALTER TABLE Buy ADD COLUMN id integer primary key not null auto_increment;
```

Then, after inserting in this table (you don't need to change your `INSERT` statement), you must get the last generated key:

```
stmt.executeUpdate(Buy1Query2);
ResultSet rsKey = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
rsKey.next();
int lastInsertId = rsKey.getInt(1);
```

Then, you must change your `SELECT` statement for:
        PreparedStatement buyquery=connection.prepareStatement("Select * from Buy where id = "+lastInsertId);

And that's it.

The other option is, as long as there cannot by repeated values in `productname` in `Buy` table, to use the following `SELECT` statement:

```
    PreparedStatement buyquery=connection.prepareStatement(
                     "Select * from Buy where productname = '"+
                                            Pname1.getText()+"'");
```

But I'd rather the first option.